# The exact definition of conjugate momentum density

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, terminology, units, notation

After checking various websites, I've seen the conjugate momentum density defined as either:
\begin{align*}
P_r ~=~ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{A}_r}
\end{align*}
or 
\begin{align*}
P_r ~=~ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_0 A_r)}.
\end{align*}

When you are working in natural units, there is no difference. However, when you *don't* take $c=1$ (or if you're working in an exotic metric), the difference is important, because $\partial_0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial (ct)} \neq \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. It may seem trivial but I think it is worth being sure.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): As usually be prepared that different authors could have different conventions of where to place various factors of $c$. One would have to check their definitions carefully to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're thinking about Minkowski space, i.e. the metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(c^2,-1,-1,-1)$. You should be aware that the dot notation is *purely* a notational shorthand, and has no other information contained in it. In particular, by definition we have
$$\dot{A}\equiv\partial_0A=\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}$$
Thus, there is no problem (in *any* metric) because the different notations don't actually differ in content.

Comment: Thanks, I had always assumed the dot was a time-only derivative.